# Noticing dockerd process on AWS EC2 is consuming high cpu, Unable to bring it down

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, containers, datadog

We have a EC2 instance where we are running 5 containers using docker along with datadog-agent container for monitoring, All of a sudden we have started noticing high cpu usage on the instance.

Usually, average cpu usage on our ec2 would not cross 20% but now it is consistently hitting 80% and upon inspection, we have noticed that none of the containers are consuming high cpu (validated this using docker stats) when we do a htop on the ec2 instance we notice that there are 5-6 processes like below which are consuming 80-100% of cpu (this is the image after restarting the docker service).

[image]

what could be the case and would be grateful if anyone could help me look in the right direction.

Thank you